# XSL: for-each select a string with umlauts

Tags: xml, xslt, diacritics

I have the following XML:

```
<FeatureGroup FeatureGroup="Bundesländer">
    <Feature>
        <FeatureValue>
            <Value LanguageCode="fr">Brandenburg</Value>
            <Value LanguageCode="de">Brandenburg</Value>
            <Value LanguageCode="en">Brandenburg</Value>
        </FeatureValue>
    </Feature>
</FeatureGroup>
```

And i want it to be transformed by xsl but i'm not able to select the FeatureGroup-Value "Bundesländer". Here is the xsl:

```
<field name="federalState">
    <xsl:for-each select="FeatureGroups/FeatureGroup[FeatureGroup = 'Bundesländer']">
        <xsl:for-each select="Feature/FeatureValue/Value[@LanguageCode= 'de']">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</field>
```

How can i select an attributes value with an umlaut in it?

Comment: Make sure you have the correct encoding in the `<?xml` tag, and that you save the file using the correct encoding.

Comment: Have you already tried entites like `&auml;` instead of the umlaut?

Comment: @Sjoerd:Yes, it's the correct encoding. Both UTF-8.

Comment: @stacker: Yes, i did try it with &auml;, but without result.

Answer (score 3):

Well XML and XPath have full support for Unicode so selecting any Unicode character is not a problem, you simply need to make sure your path selects the attribute node with `@` i.e. replace `<xsl:for-each select="FeatureGroups/FeatureGroup[FeatureGroup = 'Bundesländer']">` by `<xsl:for-each select="FeatureGroups/FeatureGroup[@FeatureGroup = 'Bundesländer']">`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems to save your file in a proper encoding (as suggested in the comment by Sjoerd), you can always use
"Umlaut entities" (same as in HTML):

> ä  = &auml;
>
> Bundesländer = Bundesl&auml;nder

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) you find a complete list.

Comment: Perhaps you should replace `[FeatureGroup = 'Bundesländer']` by `[@FeatureGroup = 'Bundesländer']` ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this wasn't your problem, but one theoretical possibility is that there are two Unicode representations of an accented letter: one as a single Unicode codepoint (composed form) and one as two Unicode codepoints (decomposed form). In XPath 1.0 they won't compare equal. In XPath 2.0, they may or may not compare equal, depending on the default collation, which is processor-dependent.

I describe this problem as theoretical because I've never actually seen it arise in practice. I think that's because most tools generate the composed form of characters unless you go out of your way to get the decomposed form.